# Installing Geofirestore with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, geofirestore

I am trying to install Geofirestore with Cocoapods. I put `pod 'Geofirestore'` in my podfile but I get an error:

`Geofirestore was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on FirebaseCore (~> 5.0.3)`

How do I install Geofirestore?

My podfile is as such:

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 7.0-beta'
pod 'SDWebImageSwiftUI'
pod 'Geofirestore'
```

Comment: Show the full Podfile. Geofirestore has old dependencies, so there's likely a conflict if you're requesting newer versions.

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Geofirestore is not compatible with FirebaseFirestoreSwift since Geofirestore depends on Firebase 5.x and FirebaseFirestoreSwift was introduced in Firebase 6.x.

Two options:

- Contact or work with Geofirestore on an update to work with recent Firestore releases.
- Drop FirebaseFirestoreSwift and use older Firebase versions for the other Firebase pods.

Comment: Do you know of another library with similar functionality that would be compatible with FirebaseFirestoreSwift?